# How to render to another page after using the useNavigate hook

Tags: reactjs, redirect, navigation, render

I'm starting with React and I have this problem where i want the user to get redirected to a whole another page after a button is pressed. I want the content to render to a new page, instead, it renders to the same page.
So let's say this is the App Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import TopHeader from './components/TopHeader';
import SlideShow from './components/SlideShow';
import Content from './components/Content';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Cards from './components/Cards';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Portofoliu from './pages/Portofoliu';
import Universitate from './pages/Universitate';
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <TopHeader />
        <SlideShow />
        <Content />
        <Cards />
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/portofoliu' element={<Portofoliu />} />
          <Route path='/universitate' element={<Universitate />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Ok, now, let's say this is the Cards component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Container, Row, Col, Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Cards.css';
import univ from '../images/i1.png';
import port from '../images/i2.png';
const Cards = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  function goToPortofoliu() {
    navigate('/portofoliu');
  }
  function goToUniversitate() {
    navigate('/universitate');
  }
  return (
    <Container className='content-container'>
      <Row>
        <Col>
          <Card className='card-content'>
            <Card.Img id='card-img' src={port} alt='poza-portofoliu' />
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Protofuliul Elevului</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>Creaza-ti propriul portofoliu</Card.Text>
              <Button onClick={goToPortofoliu}>Adauga Portofoliu</Button>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
        <Col>
          <Card className='card-content'>
            <Card.Img id='card-img' src={univ} alt='poza-cariera' />
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Universitati</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>Raspunde la cateva intrebari!</Card.Text>
              <Button variant='primary' onClick={goToUniversitate}>
                Universitate
              </Button>
            </Card.Body>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};
export default Cards;
```

Great, now, let's say the component Universitate only has an h1 tag. After the user presses the button from the Cards component, I'd like for the page to render just the h1 tag in a whole separate page with just that h1 tag, instead, it renders on the main page of the App Component.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you put in the App.js file will show up on all pages. So you are seeing all the App.js content and then showing the routed component below it. So here you have:

```
<TopHeader />
<SlideShow />
<Content />
<Cards />
// and then you have your conditional router rended components, you will always see these 4 components and then whatever the router is rending.
```

Does [this react router example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9pyfqc?file=src/Home.js) answer your question? In this example you have a card that has two buttons and will render a new component based on the selection. I would suggest adding a default `<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />` home route. In this example you can see on my App.js file I have a comment for you to comment in/out the Test component. Then you can see how it renders on "every" page. If you want to prevent `<SlideShow /> <Content /> <Cards />` from rendering on every page, then they need to be in a different component, like home.

In your example, if you are on the '/universitate' page, it will show the TopHeader, SlideShow, Content, Cards, and THEN will show the `<Universitate />` component. If you want to move the Content and Cards to a `<Home />` component, then those two would ONLY display on the home page.